# Why does a pole in the RHP imposes a lower limitation in bandwidth?

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I am studying control systems, and I have seen that a pole in the right half plane gives a limitation in bandwidth, imposing that the bandwidth of the system has to be high enough.

My question is : why does this happen?

I have seen for example that for zeros in the right half plane, the limitation is given by the fact that the phase decreases after a certain frequency, but why for a pole in the right half plane do I have a limitation as well?

Consider for example the following plant and controller:

$P(s)=\frac{10}{(s+2)(s-1)}$

$C(s)=\frac{4(s+1)}{s}$

where $P(s)$ is the plant and $C(s)$ is the controller, if I plot the Bode plot I have:

[image]

but to me it looks like that if I decrease the bandwidth the performances increases, but it happens exacly the opposite.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing some concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote the close loop transfer function as $T(s)=\frac{P(s)C(s)}{1+P(s)C(s)}$.
For a RHP-pole $p_i$, the cut-off frequency (where $\left\vert T \right \vert $ drops below $0\,\mathrm{dB}$), is bounded by the following inequality
$$
\omega_T\geq \Re(p_i)\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2+2\frac{\left\vert M_T \right \vert}{3\, \mathrm{dB}}} \right)
,$$
where $\left\vert M_T \right \vert$ is the peak gain, given in $\mathrm{dB}$. If we want this peak to be less than $3 \, \mathrm{dB}$ across all frequencies, then the bandwidth is bounded by $\omega_T \geq \Re(p_i)$.

For more information, see **Skogestad & Postlehtwaite**. *Multivariable feedback control* and **Seron et al.**. *Fundamental Limitations in Filtering and Control*.